# Count and update duplicate entries from array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reduce

I have an array with duplicated entries.
I'm looking for:

- removing all duplicate occurrences
- And increment the val propertie off an element if we find an occurrence

here is an exemple of what I have:

```
const arr = [
    {"id":"46","name":"Productivity","val":1},
    {"id":"1","name":"test","val":1},
    {"id":"43","name":"Health and Fitness","val":1},
    {"id":"46","name":"Productivity","val":1},
    {"id":"1","name":"test","val":1},
    {"id":"46","name":"Productivity","val":1}
]
```

// Wanted result

```
const result =  [
    {"id":"46","name":"Productivity","val":3},
    {"id":"43","name":"Health and Fitness","val":1},
    {"id":"1","name":"test","val":2}
]
```

[Here is a JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c2xL9ewa/4/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily achieve this using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```js
const arr = [
  { id: "46", name: "Productivity", val: 1 },
  { id: "1", name: "test", val: 1 },
  { id: "43", name: "Health and Fitness", val: 1 },
  { id: "46", name: "Productivity", val: 1 },
  { id: "1", name: "test", val: 1 },
  { id: "46", name: "Productivity", val: 1 },
];

const result = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const { id, name, val } = curr;
  const isPresent = acc.find((el) => el.id === id);
  if (!isPresent) acc = [...acc, { id, name, val }];
  else isPresent.val = isPresent.val + val;
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```